# Registration full name

Tags: 7, entities, users

I would like to edit the registration fields, but I can't find where to do it.
I want to replace the username field on the registration form with two fields for first name and last name, which are then used to create the username as `<first name> <last name>`.

Comment: Hello, Ruben; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. For which Drupal version are you asking the question?

Comment: hi kiamlaluno, I'm using Drupal 7, could find the answer for drupal 6, but not for 7 :)

Comment: thnx for the help @kiamlaluno, now let's hope for some answers :P

Answer (score 2):

There is [Auto Username](http://drupal.org/project/auto_username) for Drupal 6, and there is a Drupal 7 port of the module sitting in [the issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/1107702).
Perhaps you could test the zip that is attached to that ticket, and help fixing any bugs. ;)

Alternatively, perhaps you could make this happen using the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.